# Spark Dataframe datatype as String

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to validate the datatype of a DataFrame by writing describe as an SQL query but every time I am getting datetime as string.

1.First I tried with the below code:

```
    SparkSession sparkSession=new SparkSession.Builder().getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> df=sparkSession.read().option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").format("csv").load("/user/data/*_ecs.csv");

        try {
    df.createTempView("data");
    Dataset<Row> sqlDf=sparkSession.sql("Describe data");
    sqlDf.show(300,false);

    Output:
    +-----------------+---------+-------+
    |col_name         |data_type|comment|
    +-----------------+---------+-------+
    |id               |int      |null   |
    |symbol           |string   |null   |
    |datetime         |string   |null   |
    |side             |string   |null   |
    |orderQty         |int      |null   |
    |price            |double   |null   | 
    +-----------------+---------+-------+
```

2. I also try Custom schema but in that case i am getting exception when I am executing any query other than describe table:

   ```
   SparkSession sparkSession=new SparkSession.Builder().getOrCreate(); Dataset<Row>df=sparkSession.read().option("header","true").schema(customeSchema).format("csv").load("/use/data/*_ecs.csv");
    try {
               df.createTempView("trade_data");
       Dataset<Row> sqlDf=sparkSession.sql("Describe trade_data");
       sqlDf.show(300,false);

   Output:
   +--------+---------+-------+
   |col_name|data_type|comment|
   +--------+---------+-------+
   |datetime|timestamp|null   |
   |price   |double   |null   |
   |orderQty|double   |null   |
   +--------+---------+-------+
   ```

But if i try any query then getting the below execption:

```
Dataset<Row> sqlDf=sparkSession.sql("select DATE(datetime),avg(price),avg(orderQty) from data group by datetime");


java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.stringToTime(DateTimeUtils.scala:137)
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Custom schema which I used:
StructType customeSchema=new StructType(new StructField[] {
          new StructField("datetime",DataTypes.TimestampType,true,Metadata.empty()),
               new StructField("price",DataTypes.DoubleType,true,Metadata.empty()),
               new StructField("orderQty",DataTypes.DoubleType,true,Metadata.empty())});

Comment: The `valueOf` javadoc clearly says when an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. Please verify your data. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-

Comment: @DanW : Can you please tell why inferschema is not working ??

Answer (score 0):

1. why Inferschema is not working ??

   - for this you can find more on this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19228
   - so Datetype columns are parsed as String for current version of spark
2. If you don't want to submit your own schema, one way would be this:

   ```
   Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferschema", "true").load("example.csv");

   df.printSchema();  // check output - 1
   df.createOrReplaceTempView("df");
   Dataset<Row> df1 = sparkSession.sql("select * , Date(datetime) as datetime_d from df").drop("datetime");
   df1.printSchema();  // check output - 2

   ====================================

   output - 1:
   root
    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- symbol: string (nullable = true)
    |-- datetime: string (nullable = true)
    |-- side: string (nullable = true)
    |-- orderQty: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- price: double (nullable = true)

   output - 2:
   root
    |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- symbol: string (nullable = true)
    |-- side: string (nullable = true)
    |-- orderQty: integer (nullable = true)
    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
    |-- datetime_d: date (nullable = true)
   ```

   I'd choose this method if the number of fields to cast is not high.
3. If you want to submit your own schema:

   ```
   List<org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
   fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("datetime", DataTypes.TimestampType, true));
   fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("price",DataTypes.DoubleType,true));
   fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("orderQty",DataTypes.DoubleType,true));
   StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
   Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").schema(schema).load("example.csv");

   df.printSchema(); // output - 1

   df.createOrReplaceTempView("df");
   Dataset<Row> df1 = sparkSession.sql("select * , Date(datetime) as datetime_d from df").drop("datetime");
   df1.printSchema(); // output - 2

   ======================================
   output - 1:
   root
    |-- datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
    |-- orderQty: double (nullable = true)

   output - 2:
   root
    |-- price: double (nullable = true)
    |-- orderQty: double (nullable = true)
    |-- datetime_d: date (nullable = true)
   ```

   Since its again casting column from timestamp to Date, I don't see much use of this method. But still putting it here for your later use maybe.